# c++ 2D array row sort based on average row value

Tags: c++, arrays

Helo,

I'm wondering if there's any working method for this?
I'm trying make this work, but no luck.

```
int mat[3][3];

    mat[0][0] = 4;mat[0][1] = 5;mat[0][2] = 3;

    mat[1][0] = 3;mat[1][1] = 2;mat[1][2] = 1;

    mat[2][0] = 1;mat[2][1] = 8;mat[2][2] = 9;
```

Any idea? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a temporary data structure that is an array of tuples. The tuples would be the row index and the average of that row index. Then sort this tuple array based on the average using the standard sort() function. Then, run through the sorted tuple array to recompute the sorted matrix.

This would give you performance benefit of not copying the matrix rows during the swap done by the sort routine. If you only have 3 elements in your row, you may be okay with swap the whole row. But as you increase the number of columns the swapping would be become a bottleneck.

In 'pseudo code' you may do something like this:

```
function sort(input, numrows, numcols)
{
    pair<int, int> index[numrows];

    for (int i=0 to numrows) {
      index[i].second = i;
      // compute average of row[i] in the input matrix
      index[i].first = average_of_row(&input[i]);
    }

    // STL sort will sort the pair based on the average (.first member)
    sort(index.begin(), index.end());

    for (int i=0 to index.size())
    {
       // copy rows from input matrix to output matrix
       copy_row(&input[index[i].second], &output_matrix[i]);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no need to compute average, just compute sum (all rows have the same number of columns). This can be done with `index[i].first = accumulate(input[i], input[i] + numcols)`. Also, copy_row should be `std::copy(input[index[i].second], input[index[i].second], output_matrix[i])`

Answer (score 5):

A more idiomatically C++ way of doing this (vs. your original approach of array-of-arrays) would be to have a vector of vectors, ie. `std::vector<std::vector<int> >` and then invoke `std::sort` on the top-level vector. You can pass `sort` a custom predicate that compares two rows based on their average.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Peter's suggestion,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool comp(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    if (a.size() == 0 || b.size() == 0) return false;
    int sum_a = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
    int sum_b = accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), 0);
    return sum_a / (double)a.size() < sum_b / (double)b.size();
}

int main() {
    vector<vector<int> > mat(3, vector<int>(3));
    mat[0][0] = 4; mat[0][1] = 5; mat[0][2] = 3;
    mat[1][0] = 3; mat[1][1] = 2; mat[1][2] = 1;
    mat[2][0] = 1; mat[2][1] = 8; mat[2][2] = 9;
    sort(mat.begin(), mat.end(), comp);
    return 0;
}
```

I wasn't sure of the best way to handle empty vectors, so I just had it return false. Of course you could give `comp()` a more meaningful name.

**EDIT:** I think a better way to handle zero-sized vectors is to multiply,

```
bool comp(vector<int> a, vector<int> b) {
    int sum_a = accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0);
    int sum_b = accumulate(b.begin(), b.end(), 0);
    return sum_a * b.size() < sum_b * a.size();
}
```

Comment: Deserves an upvote for writing the code I was too lazy to do myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the rows in a multiset and overload the < operator.  Here's a 1D example:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/171028-multiset-example